# TCP File Sharing

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, file

The problem is whenever I send files the file will be sent but it is always empty (0 bytes) and I've got no clue what's causing this.

Here is the code for the sender:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.Sockets
Imports System.Threading
Public Class Form2
Dim filePath As String
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Button2.Enabled = False
    TextBox1.Enabled = False
    filePath = TextBox2.Text
    Dim sendThread As New Thread(AddressOf SendSub)
    sendThread.IsBackground = True
    sendThread.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub SendSub()
    Dim client As New TcpClient
    client.Connect(TextBox1.Text, 2222)
    Try
        Dim nstm As Stream = client.GetStream
        Dim fstm As Stream = New FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)

        Dim buffer(1024 - 1) As Byte
        Do While True
            Dim bytesRead As Integer = fstm.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
            If bytesRead = 0 Then Exit Do
            nstm.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead)
            nstm.Flush()
        Loop

        client.Close()
        nstm.Close()
        fstm.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim diag As New OpenFileDialog
    diag.InitialDirectory = "C:\"
    diag.Filter = "All Files (*.*)|*.*|All Files (*.*)|*.*"
    diag.FilterIndex = 2
    diag.RestoreDirectory = True
    If diag.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        TextBox2.Text = diag.FileName
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

And here is the code for the receiver:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.Sockets
Public Class Form1
Dim filepath As String
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Button1.Enabled = False
    TextBox1.Enabled = False
    filepath = TextBox1.Text
    Dim listenerThread As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf ListeningSub)
    listenerThread.IsBackground = True
    listenerThread.Start()
End Sub
Private Sub ListeningSub()
    Dim server As New TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 2222)
    server.Start()
    Try
        While True
            Dim c As TcpClient = server.AcceptTcpClient
            Dim s As NetworkStream = c.GetStream

            FileOpen(1, filepath, OpenMode.Binary)
            Dim buffer(1024 - 1) As Byte
            Do While True
                Dim bytesRead As Integer = s.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
                If bytesRead = 0 Then Exit Do
            Loop
            FileClose(1)

            s.Close()
            c.Close()
        End While
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim diag As New OpenFileDialog
    diag.InitialDirectory = "C:\"
    diag.Filter = "All Files (*.*)|*.*|All Files (*.*)|*.*"
    diag.FilterIndex = 2
    diag.RestoreDirectory = True
    If diag.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        TextBox1.Text = diag.FileName
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Form2.Show()
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Code review: Don't use VB files (FileOpen/Close).

Comment: @usr what else can I use instead the FileOpen/Close?

Comment: @usr can you give an example sir?

Comment: You have already used FileStream. Really easy to find something on the web. Is your question answered?

Comment: @usr I mean how can I do it on the receiving part

Comment: Ask a new question about how to use filestream. Is this one answered for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not write to the target file at all.